# How to fire scheduled notification with different content in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have the iOS app on Swift (UIKit).
Let's say I have the next array: ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","j","h","k"]

I would like to:

- fire notification every 1 hour,
- notification should take a random letter from array and fire it as a text inside notification.

While implementing that I came across with the next issues:

- local notifications fire well (every one hour), but I can't change inner text dynamically;
- push notifications (that use CloudKit database) are able to throw only if there is one of events: add/edit/delete record in CloudKit database.

Answer (score 1):

A local notification cannot run any code when it fires. It has a fixed payload and that is what displays. The notification does not pass thru your app after you schedule it; the system does the firing and displaying for you. So a local notification is probably not what you are looking for here.

Comment: I don't mind to use push notifications in conjunction with CloudKit. But according to the Apple docs they fire only if there are add/edit/delete events appeared in CloudKit database (with CloudKit records). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquerysubscription/1640414-querysubscriptionoptions